# AttributeError: 'numpy.flatiter' object has no attribute 'get_offsets' in python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

In a scatter plot matrix, I would like to draw a region in every subplot and print the points that are included in the region. I found the `LassoSelector` widget, which does exactly that. I am trying to extend its functionality for more than one subplots. I am getting the following error: `self.xys = collection.get_offsets()`,
       `AttributeError: 'numpy.flatiter' object has no attribute 'get_offsets'`.
when the line `selector = SelectFromCollection(axes, ax.flat)` is in the for loop, and I am getting the error: `self.canvas = ax.figure.canvas`,`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'figure'` when the line `selector = SelectFromCollection(ax, ax.flat)` is outside of the loop. Why does this happen?

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np

from matplotlib.widgets import LassoSelector
from matplotlib.path import Path

class SelectFromCollection(object):
    """Select indices from a matplotlib collection using `LassoSelector`.

    Selected indices are saved in the `ind` attribute. This tool highlights
    selected points by fading them out (i.e., reducing their alpha values).
    If your collection has alpha < 1, this tool will permanently alter them.

    Note that this tool selects collection objects based on their *origins*
    (i.e., `offsets`).

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : :class:`~matplotlib.axes.Axes`
        Axes to interact with.

    collection : :class:`matplotlib.collections.Collection` subclass
        Collection you want to select from.

    alpha_other : 0 <= float <= 1
        To highlight a selection, this tool sets all selected points to an
        alpha value of 1 and non-selected points to `alpha_other`.
    """
    def __init__(self, ax, collection, alpha_other=0.3):
        self.canvas = ax.figure.canvas
        self.collection = collection
        self.alpha_other = alpha_other

        self.xys = collection.get_offsets()
        self.Npts = len(self.xys)

        # Ensure that we have separate colors for each object
        self.fc = collection.get_facecolors()
        if len(self.fc) == 0:
            raise ValueError('Collection must have a facecolor')
        elif len(self.fc) == 1:
            self.fc = np.tile(self.fc, self.Npts).reshape(self.Npts, -1)

        self.lasso = LassoSelector(ax, onselect=self.onselect)
        self.ind = []

    def onselect(self, verts):
        path = Path(verts)
        self.ind = np.nonzero([path.contains_point(xy) for xy in self.xys])[0]
        self.fc[:, -1] = self.alpha_other
        self.fc[self.ind, -1] = 1
        self.collection.set_facecolors(self.fc)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()
        print(selector.xys[selector.ind])
        #selector.disconnect()

    def disconnect(self):
        self.lasso.disconnect_events()
        self.fc[:, -1] = 1
        self.collection.set_facecolors(self.fc)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.ion()
    data=np.loadtxt(r"data.txt")
    x = data[:, 3]
    x1 = data[:, 4]
    y = data[:,5]
    y1 = data[:,6]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, squeeze=True)
    for axes, marker in zip(ax.flat, ['o', 'o']):
        ax.flat[0].plot(x, y, 'r',  ls='', marker=marker)
        ax.flat[1].plot(x, x1,'r', ls='', marker=marker)
        ax.flat[2].plot(x, y1,'r', ls='', marker=marker)
        ax.flat[3].plot(y, x1,'r', ls='', marker=marker)

    selector = SelectFromCollection(ax, ax.flat)

    plt.show(block=True)
    plt.draw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a few problems that are causing your code not to work properly. There we go:

Firts of all, you modified the `SelectFromCollection` class that you got from the [LassoSelector example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/lasso_selector_demo.html) to print every selected point, but forgot a detail:

```
class SelectFromCollection(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, collection, alpha_other=0.3):
        # ...
        # No changes here...
        # ...

    def onselect(self, verts):
        path = Path(verts)
        self.ind = np.nonzero([path.contains_point(xy) for xy in self.xys])[0]
        self.fc[:, -1] = self.alpha_other
        self.fc[self.ind, -1] = 1
        self.collection.set_facecolors(self.fc)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()
        print(self.xys[self.ind]) # <- THIS LINE HAS CHANGED!!!
        #selector.disconnect()

    def disconnect(self):
        # ...
        # No changes here...
        # ...
```

Now you can use multiple instances of `SelectFromCollection`.

Then, you are also creating only one instance of `SelectFromCollection` (so only one subplot would react). Furthermore, according to the [doctsring](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/lasso_selector_demo.html) the second argument the `__init__` method expects is a `matplotlib.collections.Collection` instance.
Instead you are passing it a numpy array (in fact a numpy.Flatiter) that contains two Axes instances. If you look at the [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/lasso_selector_demo.html), there it gets a `Collection` instance returned by the `scatter`command (they use `scatter` instead of `plot`).

All in all, and restiling the loop, this is my version

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    data=np.random.rand(3,100)
    xdata = data[:-1] # all rows but last
    y = data[-1] # last row

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, squeeze=True)
    markers = ['o','^']
    selectors =[]
    for i in xrange(xdata.shape[0]):
        pts = axes[i].scatter(xdata[i], y, c='r', marker=markers[i])
        selectors.append(SelectFromCollection(axes[i], pts))

    plt.show()
```

### EDIT

If you want to do more plots, it is not hard. You can try to write more synthetic code with a for loop and so on, but an easier solution is to write directly the repetitions of the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    data=np.loadtxt(r"data.txt")
    x = data[:, 3]
    x1 = data[:, 4]
    y = data[:,5]
    y1 = data[:,6]

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

    pts1 = axes[0,0].scatter(x, y, c='r', marker='o')
    select1 = SelectFromCollection(axes[0,0], pts1)  

    pts2 = axes[1,0].scatter(x, x1, c='r', marker='o')
    select2 = SelectFromCollection(axes[1,0], pts2)  

    pts3 = axes[0,1].scatter(x, y1, c='r', marker='o')
    select3 = SelectFromCollection(axes[0,1], pts3)  

    pts4 = axes[1,1].scatter(y, x1, c='r', marker='o')
    select4 = SelectFromCollection(axes[1,1], pts4)  
    plt.show()
```

Still, **it is necessary that you change the definition of the `SelectFromCollection` class** as I said above.

Comment: Your approach works.But, not as I would like. I want to extract my data from a file. Their shape is `(122,7)` and in every row `(x,y,z,p1,p2,p3,p4)`. I want to visualize a reduced scatter plot matrix with four columns and rows. In each subplot, I would like to plot the parameters p1, p2,p3,p4 vs p1,p2,p3,p4(e.g. p1 vs p2 or p2 vs p4 and so on). Maybe, I should be clear with that from the beginning. So, another pts variable will be needed, as the x,y will be different in every subplot. Moreover, i can not anymore print the points that would be inside the `lasso`.

Comment: It is printed `<__main__.SelectFromCollection object at 0x059AF4B0>, <__main__.SelectFromCollection object at 0x059AFDB0>`.I would like also to keep the plot instead of the scatter command. Finally, every time I draw a `lasso` in a subplot, I would like the effect of the previously drawn `lasso`(in another subplot) not to be still visible . Consequently, when I draw a new `lasso` the only points that will be faded out will be those of the subplot that the `lasso` were drawn.

Comment: I edited the code with the data I want to plot in the initial question.

Comment: I added code to take your speciffic input and plot the parameter combinations you specified above. If you want more combinations I guess you can infer the formula :). I used different pts variables for clarity, but I could have used only one, since you overwrite the reference and use it again...

Comment: Regarding the `plot` vs `scatter`, the former returns a Line2D object and the latter a `PathCollection` which is what `SelectFromCollection` is expecting. I don't know how you could use the former in this case. I'm not saying there is no way, but I don't know it and in any case I think it may deserve a question by itself (specifying why you would need `plot` and not `scatter`, since maybe there is another way around it)

Comment: The code works. I already replaced the multiple `pts` with a double `for` loop, each one of each is `in range` of `ncols` and `nrows`. I can also print the points by printing `print(select1.xys[select1.ind])` in function `onselect`.Finally, let's assume that a `lasso` is drawn in axes[0][0]. Then, the points  out of the `lasso` are faded out. If a new `lasso` is drawn in axes[1][0] the points out of it are also faded out, but the points in axes[0][0], which are out of the previously drawn `lasso` are still faded out. How can I restore their original alpha value?

Comment: Something else that came in my mind. Do you have any idea how can I set the drawing of a `lasso` by holding the `shift` key and pressing the left mouse button instead of just pressing the left mouse button?probably key events must be added, but where exactly? Should I modify the above code or the `LassoSelector` widget code?

Comment: Regarding the buttons and so on, you should probably rewrite the `lasso` widget. It is coded for a kind of specific and inflexible way of work, and the fact that uses mouse clicks and specifically  from button=1 it's hard coded on the class definition. It is not extremely complicated, however...

Comment: Unselecting... I would say that the right way would probably imply redesigning the whole `SelectFromCollection` class. However, for a quick dirty way could be saving all the `selector' in a list, and at the beginning of the `onselect` method iterate over all `selector` items and setting the alpha channel to 1 by `selector.fc[:-1]=1` and `selector.collection.set_facecolors(self.fc)`.

Comment: I modified the code for triggering a lasso with shift+lmb. It was piece of cake!! :)